# postgresql combine 2 unrelated tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables: alarms and cctvs.

Alarms table consist of: alarm_ID and date.

CCTVs table also consist of: cctv_ID and date.

I would like to combine both tables such that it results in a table with three columns: cctv_ID, alarm_ID and date. cctv_ID value would be null if it has an alarm_ID and alarm_ID would be null if it has a cctv_ID.

How do I combine these 2 tables together?

alarm table:

```
alarm_ID  | Date
1         | 1/1/10
```

cctv table:

```
cctv_ID   | Date
1         | 2/1/10
```

final table should look like:

```
alarm_ID | CCTV_ID | Date
1        | null    | 1/1/10
null     | 1       | 2/1/10
```

I have this code currently:

```
with alarms as(
select alarm_id, last_maintenance_date
from REMOTE_SECURITY.alarms
where last_maintenance_date < '4/4/18'),
cctvs as (
select cctv_id, last_maintenance_date
from REMOTE_SECURITY.cctvs
where last_maintenance_date <'4/4/18')
select * from alarms
union
select * from cctvs
;
```

But this code gives me just the alarm_id column and the date column and it merges the cctv_id in the same column so I dont know which is an alarm and which is a cctv!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such a logic by contribution of `case..when` statement :

```
select (case when col0 = 'a' then 1 end) as alarm_ID, 
       (case when col0 = 'c' then 1 end) as CCTV_ID, 
       q.last_maintenance_date as Date 
  from
  (with alarms(alarm_ID,last_maintenance_date) as
          (select 1, date'2010-01-01'),
        cctvs(cctv_ID,last_maintenance_date) as
          (select 1, date'2010-01-02')
   select 'a' as col0,a.* from alarms a
   union all
   select 'c' as col0,c.* from cctvs c
  ) q;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/YMWCOC54132)

Answer (score 3):

Use [UNION](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-union/)

```
select alarm_id,'' AS cctv_id, last_maintenance_date
from REMOTE_SECURITY.alarms
where last_maintenance_date <'4/4/18')
UNION
select '' AS alarm_id,cctv_id, last_maintenance_date
from REMOTE_SECURITY.cctvs
where last_maintenance_date <'4/4/18')
```